# 演唱会 vs 音乐会 difference

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage

Based on the dictionary, it seems that both 演唱会 & 音乐会 means concert. I did further research and read somewhere that 演唱会 = concert (outdoor & indoor) with many ppl and lots of shouting and cheering while 音乐会 = choir or those indoor concerts where there are fewer ppl and just clap but no loud cheering. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

> 演(perform)
>
> 唱 (singing)
>
> 会 (gathering)
>
> 演唱会  = (singing) concert

The key word is '唱'. No matter it is a solo or a group concert, the performer(s) will sing songs.

*Sometimes instrumental music might be inserted in the program, but the majority of the show is about singing*

> 演奏 (perform musical instrument)
>
> 演奏会 = (instrumental) concert

The key word is '奏'. In a instrumental music concert, the performer(s) will perform instrumental music.

*Some singing performance might be added as bonus, but the main draw is the instrumental music*

> 音乐 (music)
>
> 音乐会 (music) concert

A music concert can be a mix of singing and instrumental music.

演唱会 and 演奏会 mostly refer to concerts performed by professional singers or musicians and you have to buy ticket to attend

However, free events with amateur performers can still call themselves 演唱会 or 演奏会

Commercial 音乐会 (music concert) are relatively rare compare to commercial 演唱会 (singing concert) and commercial 演奏会 (instrumental concert)

Answer (score 0):

If you say you run a 演唱会 recently, I would imagine you were on a big stage that is far and high. Fans were screaming and robbing your gloves. You will sing many songs without a break until you passed out.

If you say you performed in a 音乐会, I would thought you play kazoo for 3 seconds in your school for celebrate the new year.

I just kidding.